# IIS7 What unit does time-taken have in a w3c-log?

Tags: iis-7, iis

I'm trying to analyze some IIS7 logs (W3C format) and am interesting in the `time-taken` field and its unit.

According to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786596(v=ws.10).aspx) the unit is milliseconds.

```
The length of time that the action took, in milliseconds.
```

According to the [w3c documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html) it's in seconds

```
Time taken for transaction to complete in seconds, field has type <fixed>
```

What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Milliseconds is correct. A time-taken value of 1000 is one second.

You'll find that the numbers are often 53ms or other low values like that for your static images and files, and the time-taken value increases from there depending on the page and how quickly it runs.